# React Native overlapping views with elevation not work

Tags: react-native, button, elevation, component-design

[image: Card elevation with overlapping button]

I want to show button above card with elevation, but my problem is button goes behind card. If I remove elevation of card then button shows above card. I want both button above card and card with elevation. How can I achieve this?

Currently I put button below card and give minus marginTop to button, It's working without card elevation but not with elevation.

Note: I tried absolute position and zIndex both but not worked.

Comment: Have you tried adding position relative to the card with a given z-index and the button position absolute?

Comment: Yes I tried this but not worked.

Comment: @ManuelBlanco See my updated question.